# LWC Lightning-card slot alignment issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-card, slots

It appears that I can't put a lightning-input in a slot. I would like the input and button to line up side by side on the right, preferably in line with the lightning-card title. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

[image]

HTML:

```
                            <lightning-card class="slds-size_12-of-12" title="Requests" icon-name="standard:lead_list" variant="narrow">
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" slot="actions">                                               
                                    <div class="slds-m-top_small slds-m-bottom_medium"> 
                                        <lightning-input
                                            class="slds-m-top_none slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-right_xx-large"
                                            onchange={searchRR}
                                            name="enter-search"
                                            label=""
                                            type="search"
                                            placeholder="Search this list..."
                                            slot="actions">
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                    <template if:false={isPortalUser}>
                                        <div class="slds-float_right">
                                            <lightning-button
                                                variant="neutral" 
                                                label="New" 
                                                title="New" 
                                                onclick={handleClick} 
                                                class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                                                slot="actions">
                                            </lightning-button>
                                        </div>
                                    </template>
                                </div>
. . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input fields, by default, have a label. Use the `variant="label-hidden"` to remove this extra space. Also, using `slot` on each element moves them all up to the "top" which results in the weird appearance. Remove the slot attributes on all except the top `div`.

```
<lightning-card class="slds-size_12-of-12" title="Requests" icon-name="standard:lead_list" variant="narrow">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" slot="actions">
        <lightning-input class="slds-size_8-of-12" onchange={searchRR} name="enter-search" type="search"
            placeholder="Search this list..." variant="label-hidden" label="label">
        </lightning-input>
        <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="New" title="New" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-p-left_large">
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

Edit: [Demo](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/jyzFZ0IW5ZArB7wF2xt7/src/app.html?p=stories).